# Sunburst diagram is not being plotted in Jupyter notebook at all

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab, plotly-python, sunburst-diagram

I want to plot a sunburst diagram where the first ring is "population" and the second ring is subdivided into the following categories according to their weight: [num_safe_hood1, num_safe_hood2, num_safe_hood3, num_safe_hood4, num_safe_hood5]. Plotted another version that doesn't implement the aforementioned "second ring". I have included both sets of code as well as any other relevant code. I have also included the outputs. If you need anymore information please ask!

For better context this is kind of what im going for incase the explanation is confusing:

goal for how the graph should look:

[image: goal for how the graph should look]

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Specify the path to your CSV file
csv_file_path = 'GunOwnerSruvey.csv'
data = pd.read_csv("GunOwnerSruvey.csv")
data

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.colors

def plotSunburst(data):
    total_pop = len(data)
    
    # First ring
    num_gunOwners = unionOf(data, ('va4', [1], True))
    num_gunOwners_carry = unionOf(data, ('va4', [1], True), ('vb11', [1], True))
    num_gunOwners_carry_disp = unionOf(data, ('vb11', [1], True), ('va4', [1], True), ('vc27', [99], False))
    
    # Second ring
    num_safe_hood1 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [1], True))
    num_safe_hood2 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [2], True))
    num_safe_hood3 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [3], True))
    num_safe_hood4 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [4], True))
    num_safe_hood8 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [8], True))
    
    population = ["Total Population", "Gun Owners", "Gun Owners Carry", "Gun Owners Carry Disp",
                  "Safe Hood 1", "Safe Hood 2", "Safe Hood 3", "Safe Hood 4", "Safe Hood 8"]
    values = [total_pop, num_gunOwners, num_gunOwners_carry, num_gunOwners_carry_disp,
              num_safe_hood1, num_safe_hood2, num_safe_hood3, num_safe_hood4, num_safe_hood8]
    parents = ["", "Total Population", "Gun Owners", "Gun Owners Carry",
               "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population"]
    
    # Create a color scale using Plotly's built-in color scales
    color_scale = plotly.colors.sequential.YlOrRd
    colors = [color_scale[(len(population) - 1) - i] for i in range(len(population))]
    
    # Create the sunburst chart
    fig = go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
        labels=population,
        parents=parents,
        values=values,
        branchvalues="total",
        hoverinfo="label+value+percent parent",
        marker=dict(colors=colors)  # Set the colors for each slice
    ))
    
    # Customize the layout
    fig.update_layout(
        title="Population Subsets",
        width=600,
        height=600
    )
    
    # Display the chart
    fig.show(renderer='iframe')

plotSunburst(data)
```

output to this code is:
[output for broken code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LYR5.png)

here is the block of code that does work and the output:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.colors


def plotSunburst(data):
    total_pop = len(data)
    num_gunOwners = unionOf(data, ('va4', [1], True))
    num_gunOwners_carry = unionOf(data, ('va4', [1], True), ('vb11', [1], True))
    num_gunOwners_carry_disp = unionOf(data, ('vb11', [1], True), ('va4', [1], True), ('vc27', [99], False))

    num_safe_hood1 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [1], True))
    num_safe_hood2 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [2], True))
    num_safe_hood3 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [3], True))
    num_safe_hood4 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [4], True))
    num_safe_hood8 = unionOf(data, ('v1a', [8], True))

    population = ["Total Population", "Gun Owners", "Gun Owners Carry", "Gun Owners Carry Disp"]
    values = [total_pop, num_gunOwners, num_gunOwners_carry, num_gunOwners_carry_disp]
    parents = ["", "Total Population", "Gun Owners", "Gun Owners Carry"]
    
    # Define color for each slice
    #colors = ["#ff7f0e", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728"]
    #colors = ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728"]
    color_scale = plotly.colors.sequential.YlOrRd
    colors = [color_scale[len(population) - i] for i in range(len(population))]
    #colors = ["ff7f0e", "#ff7f0e", "#2ca02c", "#d62728"]

    # Create the sunburst chart
    fig = go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
        labels=population,
        parents=parents,
        values=values,
        branchvalues="total",
        hoverinfo="label+value+percent parent",
        marker=dict(colors=colors)  # Set the colors for each slice

        
    ))

    # Customize the layout
    fig.update_layout(
        title="Population Subsets",
        width=1200,
        height=1200
    )

    # Display the chart
    fig.show(renderer='iframe')

plotSunburst(data)
```

output for working code:

[image: output for working code:]

I tried changing the way color was calculated but it did nothing. Im really new to Sunbursts plots and plotly so anything helps! Even course on how to do sunbursts.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide sample data to test a potential solution?